# orchard CMS display top 10 and rss

Tags: orchardcms

I have 2 question,

I have created a multi tenant using orchard, is there a way to display recent blog post from multi tenant? Or if I can change the question, because it's using RSS, is there any way to display RSS using orchard?

The second question, is there any module that can show us a popular post? I try to instal http://gallery.orchardproject.net/Packages/Orchard.Module.galgodage.TopViews
but still not working at all, I already added the userview part to the blog post content but still the popular post not showing anything.

Thanks

Comment: That module is last updated 5 years ago, so I don't think it is compatible with your orchard version

Comment: yes, is there any other module to do the same thing? I've looked every where and coulnd't find any

Comment: The Vandelay module has a feature to show a RSS feed: https://github.com/bleroy/vandelay. The feature is called "Remote RSS".

As for that top views module, download it, rename the file as a `.zip` and extract the source code. You can then debug it and see what's preventing it from working on modern Orchard instances.

As a side note, it's usually best to ask only one question at a time.

Comment: Hi Bertrand I already succed with the rss feed. thanks